# Losing SQL connections

Tags: sql-server, performance, networking

sql servr 2005 - Standard; one dedicated sql server (VM); windows server 2003;  Small databases;

About once a week we lose all sql connections. It seems to fix itself after about 5-10 minutes.

*System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding*.

We don't have a fully qualified DBA; it's kind of a joint effort here.  Can somebody give me some general ideas for troubleshooting the network side and the application side?

We already ran a few tuning profiles and ran through Database Tuning Advisor to apply indexing recommendations.  It would sure be nice if there was a way to take a snapshot of what was running on sql server when these 100% cpu spikes occured, but sometimes we're not around.

Is it common to throttle CPU for certain processes?  Can this be done with Windows server 2003?  For example, if security apps were making cpu spike to 100%, is there a way to limit their cpu usage?

Any advice is appreciated.   thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Good call on the TCP enabling. What is the database used for? It could be a front end application running a process once a week (think slow SharePoint crawl) that is sucking up CPU. Windows Server 2003 has Error Logs you can check to see what is going on in the OS and App environment. Start-->Administrative Tools-->Event Viewer-->Windows Logs-->Application. There should be more information there. Hope this helps and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Check network connectivity - run a continous ping and check wehterh you get a problem at the same time. Mabe you do not really have a database issue, but one on the network level. THe only cases (2) i Know of that behavior were network related (crap driver and REALLY Overloaded - at times - 10mbit link).

Answer (score 0):

What connection type are you using?  If using Named pipes, try switching to TCP connections.  We had similar problems with our 2005 server, and disabling Named pipes and forcing use of TCP connections took care of it for us.